# New Records inserted from one application is not reflecting in other application of same server using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using a JPA 2.0 with eclipse link implementation in my project.

The scenario is we have 2 application say A,B in the server tomcat, both applications uses the same database.
When we started the server the no of records(and respective data also) of a table called Employee are same when we checked from these two applications.

But when I inserted any new records from Application A is not reflecting in application B.

Is this because application B is not aware of changes done by A and is it uses lazy loading (as B application persistence context does not have any changes) ?

If it the reason then how can I get all these records from that table from application B ?

What are the reasons for this?

Note:- Employee table has no relationships.

What changes I need to perform ?

Comment: Are your changes committed to database from application A before reading from app B?

Comment: Are the new records in application A definitely committed to the database? Can you see them via the database UI.

Comment: yeah, each and every record is committed to database and I am able to see them in database.@ Rohit and @ Alan

Comment: Try it with L2 cache turned off, which I think is a must if you have multiple applications CRUD-ing the same database.